# Good architecture for Azure for streaming analytics?

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics, azure-iot-hub

I have JSON data coming from sensors per seconds to Azure IoT hub. Data is time series with 15 variables. I want to process this data real time using c# application which is quite complex and send outputs events to some other service(can be storage or PowerBI) 
What do you think is the best architectural approach for it?
1. Try to process the data in stream analytics with c# code, I know there is  .Net support for azure stream analytics but i think is very premature? Any experience in this approach?Does azure stream analytics support complex c# algorithms? 
2. Store data to azure data lake and use data lake analytics to process the data?

Your experiences and recommendations are very much appreciated.
Many thanks

Comment: Since IoT Hub use an Azure Event Hub under the hoods you could write an event processor host that reads and processes the data. See https://blog.eldert.net/iot-integration-of-things-processing-event-hubs-from-azure-cloud-service/ for an example.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Try to process the data in stream analytics with c# code

Azure Stream Analytics uses Stream Analytics Query Language to perform transformations and computations over streams of events. The C# SDK is just a way to create and run a Stream Analytics job. All the transformations and computations work should be written in Stream Analytics Query Language.

> 2. Store data to azure data lake and use data lake analytics to process the data?

Stream Analytics is better in **real-time** data handle scenarios. I suggest you combine these 2 ways together. Use Azure Stream Analytics to do a **preliminary and necessary** data processing and conversion and output the data to azure data lake and use data lake analytics to further process the data.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for you answer. 1. solution is very hard to implement as i already have code very complex code in c# so converting them to stream analytics script is very hard if not impossible. I have gone with IoThub--> stream analytics-->azure function-->power bi solution. what do you think about it?

Comment: It would be fine. You could do the complex algorithm in azure function.

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to alternative solutions you could also use a HTTP API like [Stride](https://www.stride.io/), which enables the creation of networks of continuous SQL queries, chained together, with the ability to subscribe to streams of changes as a means to streaming data out to applications.

If your computational needs fit within the confines of SQL this approach might work well for you. You can check out the [Stride docs](https://www.stride.io/docs) to see some examples.